# What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

What is fastest solution to flatten lists which contain other lists of arbitrary length?

For example `[1, 2, [3, 4, [5],[]], [6]]` would become `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

There can be arbitrarily many levels. Some of the list objects can be strings, which mustn't be flattened into their sequential characters in the output list.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/406822/197011) from a [previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) should do what you want.  (Voting to close as duplicate).

Comment: @GreenMatt, it's only a duplicate if the *question* is the same, not the answer. It's clear that the other question is for a single level of nesting, and simpler solutions are more appropriate.

Comment: @Mark Ransom:  I thought I'd seen this before, and that was what I found when I searched.  Guess I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: Please stop removing the system-generated "Possible duplicate" banner. The second link has the answer to your question.

Comment: Disagree, the answer might happen to be the same, but the question needs to work for arbitrarily nested lists and so isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: @Rory I'm sorry, even the questions look (almost) identical to me. Can you highlight the difference? Also, what does removing the duplicate text solve?

Comment: I am surprised that this is not available in a standard library, like itertools or smthing

Comment: @vaultah the apparent difference was that this question *supposedly* asks about performance. However, performance considerations would belong to the consideration of the original question anyway, and *the accepted answer here explicitly disclaims performance*, so this question is a crystal clear duplicate.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach that is string friendly:

```
nests = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5],['hi']], [6, [[[7, 'hello']]]]]

def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i

print list(flatten(nests))
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'hi', 6, 7, 'hello']
```

Note, this doesn't make any guarantees for speed or overhead use, but illustrates a recursive solution that hopefully will be helpful.

Comment: This is just a beautiful application of yield. Well done ...

Comment: In Python 3.3+, you could use `yield from flatten(i)` instead of `for j in flatten(i): yield j`

Comment: you could also do `if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):` instead. but great solution regardless.

Comment: What if it's a set? I used `if hasattr(i, '__iter__'):`

Comment: String types cause an infinite recursion with `hastattr(i,  '__iter__')`.  I filtered those out `if hasattr(i, '__iter__') and not isinstance(i, str):`

Comment: You seem to assume that `container` is a list. You'll get a list of characters if you call `flatten('test')`. There's no need for a nested `for` loop. That's what recursion is for!

Comment: Recursive is not fast...

Comment: This will raise a `RecursionError` if the depth of your list is more than 1000. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it

Answer (score 31):

It doesn't *have* to be recursive. In fact, an iterative solution is often faster because of the overhead involved in function calls. Here's an iterative version I wrote a while back:

```
def flatten(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):
    for i, x in enumerate(items):
        while i < len(items) and isinstance(items[i], seqtypes):
            items[i:i+1] = items[i]
    return items
```

Haven't tested the performance of this specific implementation, but it is probably not so great because of all the slice assignments, which could end up moving a lot of memory around. Still, don't assume it has to be recursive, or that it's simpler to write it that way.

This implementation does have the advantage of flattening the list "in place" rather than returning a copy, as recursive solutions invariably do. This could be useful when memory is tight. If you want a flattened copy, just pass in a shallow copy of the list you want to flatten:

```
flatten(mylist)                # flattens existing list
newlist = flatten(mylist[:])   # makes a flattened copy
```

Also, this algorithm is not limited by the Python recursion limit because it's not recursive. I'm certain this will virtually never come into play, however.

2021 edit: it occurs to me that the check for the end of the list might be better handled with `try`/`except` because it will happen only once, and getting the test out of the main loop could provide a performance beneft. That would look like:

```
def flatten(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):
    try:
        for i, x in enumerate(items):
            while isinstance(items[i], seqtypes):    
                items[i:i+1] = items[i]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return items
```

With some further tweaking to use the `x` returned by `enumerate` instead of accessing `items[i]` so much, you get this, which is either mildly or significantly faster than the original version up top, depending on the size and structure of your lists.

```
def flatten(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):
    try:
        for i, x in enumerate(items):
            while isinstance(x, seqtypes):    
                items[i:i+1] = x
                x = items[i]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return items
```

Comment: I thought modifying a sequence you're looping over was kind of dangerous?

Comment: @Mark this is write-once code :). Make a note to warn future editors and move on with your life.

Comment: @Triptych, I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: It's not necessarily "dangerous" to modify a list you're iterating, it's just that you can wind up skipping elements you don't mean to if you delete things. To avoid this, I use `enumerate()` and access the list only by index, rather than using the value (`x`) yielded by the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation kindall, using an index does make it safer. You're still relying on lazy evaluation of `enumerate` for proper results, and I doubt that's guaranteed behavior (can you tell I have a C++ background?)

Comment: `enumerate()` is dead-simple and is documented as being lazy (i.e., returning an iterator that yields sequential index values). The behavior of `iter()` on a list (using an incrementing index with `__getitem__()` and comparing it to `len()` on each iteration, which works even as the length changes) is also documented. So, although it kind of looks like a hack, it's actually pretty safe barring significant changes to the language.

Comment: range instead of enumerate will also do the trick.

Comment: In python usually the recursive option is more efficient than the iterative one. The only risk is hitting the recursion limit.

Comment: You're right for this particular situation. Building a new list with a recursive solution is going to move memory around a lot less than my solution and this should more than make up for the overhead of function calls.

Comment: @kindall. Why the snippet below behaves differently than yours (python 3.4)?    `def flatten(items, seqtypes=(list, tuple)):
    for i in range(len(items)):
        while isinstance(items[i], seqtypes):
            items[i:i+1] = items[i]
    return items`

Comment: I'm trying to flatten every item in a list, which can contain strings, integer, floats, and lists containing those elements. This solution does not work in my case--for example, floats are not iterable, so "for i, x in enumerate(items):" throws a TypeError if there are any lone floats in the list. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nolanconaway The routine as written skips anything that's not a list or a tuple, so what you're saying happens can never happen.

Comment: I am surprised this does not have more votes. I ascribe it to the fact that you have to read carefully to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist!

Comment: This won't work if there is an empty list involved and I'm not sure there is a nice way to change that - since it relies on modifying in-place + enumerate

Comment: @user3467349 What doesn't work about it if there's an empty list? What would you expect to happen that isn't?

Comment: @kindall e.g. `[[]]` should produce `[]` or `[[], 1]` should produce `[1]`.

Comment: @kindall To amend what I said `[[], 1]` works -- but `flatten([1, []])` does not and neither does `flatten([[]])`.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for finding that.

Comment: The problem was when the empty list was the last item, it would delete the last item, and then on the next iteration it would try to check the last item to see if it was a sequence, but it wasn't there anymore.

Answer (score 10):

This function should be able to quickly flatten nested, iterable containers without using any recursion:

```
import collections

def flatten(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    array, stack = collections.deque(), collections.deque()
    while True:
        try:
            value = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            if not stack:
                return tuple(array)
            iterator = stack.pop()
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, str) \
               and isinstance(value, collections.Iterable):
                stack.append(iterator)
                iterator = iter(value)
            else:
                array.append(value)
```

After about five years, my opinion on the matter has changed, and this may be even better to use:

```
def main():
    data = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5], []], [6]]
    print(list(flatten(data)))


def flatten(iterable):
    iterator, sentinel, stack = iter(iterable), object(), []
    while True:
        value = next(iterator, sentinel)
        if value is sentinel:
            if not stack:
                break
            iterator = stack.pop()
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            yield value
        else:
            try:
                new_iterator = iter(value)
            except TypeError:
                yield value
            else:
                stack.append(iterator)
                iterator = new_iterator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```