# Search in a list of lists and elements

Tags: python, list, membership

Given a list of lists `A` with at most one layer of nesting, and an element to search for…

```
A = [1,2,3,[4,5,6,7],8,9,10]
to_find = 5
```

What is the fastest way to check whether an element with value 5 exists in `A` or not? List won't be sorted, and the index of element is of no concern.

I can iterate through `A` and check if element is a list and then check in there recursively.

Is there any better and faster way to do it?

Comment: How many levels of nesting can be in `A`?

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: Single level : A = [1,2,3,[4,5,6,7],8,9,10,[11,12,13]]. It will never be A = [1,2,3,[4,5,[6,7,8]]]. But I would like to know that use case too.

Comment: @JavierConde if the value in to_find is present in A or not.

Comment: is the list always sorted?

Comment: @letsc - This isn't a duplicate of that question. That question asks if it's possible to find the index of an entire sublist, while this one looks for an element within the `list` and within all sublists.

Comment: But 5 *doesn't* exist in A... also see [What is the fastest wa to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python) and [Making flat list out of list-of-lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - SHouldve shared this answer. It gives the _coordinates_ of the element being searched

Answer (score 0):

Given the condition of "a list of lists" and "at most one level of nesting":

```
def search(A, to_find):
    return any(1 for x in A if (x == to_find or (isinstance(x, list) and to_find in x)))
```

(Edited in case you happen to look for a Falsy value like 0)