# sum of surrounding elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code which calculates the sum of the numbers beside it.

For example, `list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`, the new list = `[30 (10+20), 60 (10+20+30), 90 (20+30+40), 120 (30+40+50), 90 (40+50)]`. => final list = `[30, 60, 90, 120, 90]`.

At the moment my idea was of using a for loop but it was totally off.

Comment: Share your code with us

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling or sliding window iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating triplets using `zip`:

```
# pad for first and last triplet
lst = [0] + original + [0]
# summarize triplets
sums = [sum(triplet) for triplet in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:])]
```

Example:

```
>>> original = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> lst = [0] + original + [0]
>>> sums = [sum(triplet) for triplet in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:])]
>>> sums
[30, 60, 90, 120, 90]
>>>
```

Comment: If this answers your question you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guy's flatten function [What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python)

Take the result of the flattened lists of lists and sum the collection normally with a for loop, or a library that provides a count utility for collections.