# TypeError: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

New to Python. I was working with numpy when i came across nditer() which iterates over multi-dimensional arrays to give us scalar. I am a bit confused how it works or behaves.

```
arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
for x in np.nditer(arr2):
    print(x,end=" ")
```

It gives out 1 2 3 4 5 6 
However, if I change the no of elements in one the arrays, it's throwing an error.

```
arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7]])
for x in np.nditer(arr2):
    print(x,end=" ")
```

**TypeError**: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled

**What is it I am doing wrong, or nditer() only works with arrays with regular shape? Is there any way i can get scalar values from an ndarray with irregular shape(not using for loop of course)?**

Comment: Don't bother with `nditer`.  It usually isn't needed, and confusing for beginners.  Try to avoid iteration on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The first case produces a 2d numeric array:

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In [2]: arr
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [3]: arr.shape
Out[3]: (2, 3)
```

You can easily reshape such an array:

```
In [4]: arr.ravel()
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Whole array operations like this are much preferred to loops or another (hidden) iteration (in Python code).

The second case does not produce a 2d array:

```
In [5]: arr2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]])
<ipython-input-5-4a78eda0f1a8>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  arr2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]])
In [6]: arr2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]], object)
In [7]: arr2
Out[7]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
In [8]: arr2.shape
Out[8]: (2,)
```

That's a 2 element array containing lists.  It's similar to the source list of lists.

`ravel` won't work because it is already 1d.  However we can concatenate the lists into one array:

```
In [9]: np.hstack(arr2)
Out[9]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

We don't need to use `numpy` with such a list of lists.

```
In [10]: alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
In [12]: [i for j in alist for i in j]
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

===

`np.nditer` needs stronger disclaimers.  It is best viewed as bridge to writing compiled code (with `cython`), not as primary tool in Python code.  It does not improve speed or avoid "loops".  There are lots of bells-n-whistles that may useful, but only confuse beginners.

```
In [13]: for x in np.nditer(arr):
    ...:     print(x, x.shape, type(x))
    ...: 
1 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
2 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
3 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
4 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
5 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6 () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As you used it, `x` is a numpy array with shape `()` (0d). Occasionally that's useful, but will most likely just confuse a beginner.

Working from your error message and the docs, I can iterate on `arr2`:

```
In [16]: for x in np.nditer(arr2, flags=['refs_ok']):
    ...:     print(x, x.shape, type(x))

[1, 2, 3] () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[4, 5, 6, 7] () <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As before `x` is a 0d array, only in this case the element of that array is an object, a list.  So that doesn't help if your goal is a flattened iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the ndarray by using:

```
arr2.sum()
# Result will be: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Then you can continue to get the scalar values in a single for-loop.

More detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641280/flatten-list-of-lists-and-scalars).

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that when you declare `arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7]])` the result is not a structured data and it will be assigned as a array of type object that contains a list of lists:

```
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4,5,6,7])], dtype=object)
```

and when you enter a structured data the output will be a array with the type of your inputs (int64, float64, etc) and with a corresponding dimension.

If you have a group of lists with different sizes the best solution is to make a list containing all elements and iterate over them. And if you want to stick with numpy you can do `np.concatenate([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]])` which will return a flatten array of dimension 1 that you could also iterate over.

```
import numpy as np

arr2 = np.concatenate([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7]])
for x in np.nditer(arr2):
    print(x,end=" ")
```