# how to check if a substring exist in the list having several sublists?

Tags: python, sublist

Let's say I have a list such as:

```
example_of_list = [[['aaaa'],['bbbb'],['cccc']], [['aabsd'],['fdwewd'],['dsfss']], [['sssss'],['ddddd'],['fffff']]]
```

And I want to check if my_list contains a substring

```
sub_sting = 'aaa'
```

So, In that case, this will give 'True' because I have 'aaaa' on the list as a sublist.

How to check this thing?

I already considered 'in' or 'str.contains', but it seems it doesn't give a proper response.

Comment: Your `my_list`  will raise `NameError`

Comment: corrected @Abdul Niyas P M

Comment: It will raise `NameError` because `aaaa`, `bbbb` and so forth is not defined variables. I guess you meant for them to be strings correct?

Comment: Ah. you are right. I changed it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from itertools import chain

def contains(lst, substr):
    return any(substr in s for s in chain(*chain(*lst)))
```

You can use the function in this way:

```
lst = [[['aaaa'], ['bbbb'], ['cccc']],
       [['aabsd'], ['fdwewd'], ['dsfss']],
       [['sssss'], ['ddddd'], ['fffff']]]
substr = "aaa"

print(contains(lst, substr)) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten the list, then iterate through it. I got the flatten function from [What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python)

```
example_list = [[['aaaa'],['bbbb'],['cccc']], [['aabsd'],['fdwewd'],['dsfss']], [['sssss'],['ddddd'],['fffff']]]

def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i

new_list = list(flatten(example_list))
for elem in new_list:
    if ('aaa' in elem):
        print(elem)
```