# Python Set of All Element in a Nested List

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists, try-except

I’m trying to have all element in a nested list return in the form of set through this function, but errors occurred.

```
list = [[0,4], [2,4], 5, [[[7,2], 3], 4]]

def setof(list):
  bag = set()
  for item in list:
    try: bag.add(item)
    except TypeError: bag.add(setof(item))
  return bag

print(setof(list))

Errors:
try: bag.add(item)
TypeError: unhashable type: ‘list’
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
print(setof(list))
except TypeError: bag.add(setof(item))
TypeError: unhashable the: ‘set’
```

Does anyone know why did this happen or how to fix it, or a better way of doing it? This is my first time here. Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @SamimHakimi The error is in the question

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python) you could just call `set(flatten(data))` and that would work

Comment: It would pay to put your code, error, and expected output in separate code blocks. More information on [crafting questions can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bag.add(setof(item))` is trying to add a set as an element of `bag`, not combine the sets. Use

```
bag.update(setof(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from `set.add(list)`. This is not something Python sets accept. So, you want to turn all the inner lists into sets. Try this:

```
def setof(lst):
    bag = set()
    for item in lst:
        try:
            bag.add(set(item))
        except TypeError:
            bag.add(set([item]))
    return bag
```