# How to flatten an irregular tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, flatten

I have a tuple of tuples like this:

```
(('int', 3), (('int', 50), (('int', 4), ('int', 99))))
```

And I want to get a single flattened tuple like this:

```
(('int', 3), ('int', 50), ('int', 4), ('int', 99))
```

The nesting of tuples can be arbitrary.
Most of the questions I found here were about arbitrary flattening of lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: Not exactly.
But I was able to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824484/11961946) and make some changes to get the desired solution.

Comment: you can flatten it and later use for-loop to group two element to create back tuples `('int', 3)`. OR get code for flattening and use some `if/else` to check if you have tuple with `(text, numer)` and skip flattening for these elements

Comment: The same recursive technique applies; just use different detection for the base case. Or re-create the pairs afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use any method to create flatten list and use `if/else` to check if you have tuple `("text", integer)` and don't flatten this element.

```
def flatten(data):
    # check if you have tuple ("text", integer)
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 2 and isinstance(data[0], str) and isinstance(data[1], int):
        # returns it as tuple with single element: (("text", integer),)
        result = [data]
        #print(data)
        return tuple(result)

    # flatten other elements
    result = []
    for item in data:
        result += flatten(item)
    return tuple(result)

data = (('int', 3), (('int', 50), (('int', 4), ('int', 99))))
data = flatten( data )
print(data)
```

Result:

```
(('int', 3), ('int', 50), ('int', 4), ('int', 99))
```