# How can I write a condition that if a variable is a list it does one thing and if it is not it does another

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I want to write a program that turns:

```
L=[1,3,[5,[2,6],7],[4,8,[9,10]]]
```

to:

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I wrote this function but I do not know what condition to write to recognize whether it is a list variable or not

```
def f(n):
    a=[]
    for i in n :
        if i==list :
           return f(i)
        else:
            a.append(i)
    return a
```

If you have a better solution to this problem or you know how to write this condition please help me

Comment: What are you trying to do ? please, explain what `f` is expected to perform ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to flatten arbitrarily nested lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823877/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `recursion` which is a great start.

What you are missing is checking the type of item, you can do this in your condition with `type(i)` and check against the `list` type like `type(i) == list` and iterate it then

Also, you cant declare your output variable inside the function as it will get cleaned every time, so pull it out.

Lastly, why do we use `recursion` - because the levels of nesting cannot be predetermined based on your question.

Working code below

```
list1 = [1,3,[5,[2,6],7],[4,8,[9,10]]]
result=[]
def flatList(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == list:
            flatList(i)
        else:
            result.append(i)
            
flatList(list1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

While looping through n, you can check if an item is a list by doing:

```
if type(i) is list:
   # do something for list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`list.extend`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/extend.html):

```py
def f(n):
    a=[]
    for i in n :
        if isinstance(i,list):
            a.extend(f(i))
        else:
            a.append(i)
    return a
```

That only works for lists, if you want any iterable use `collections.Iterable`:

```
import collections


# ...
        if isinstance(i,collections.Iterable):
```

```
>>> l = [1,3,[5,[2,6],7],[4,8,[9,10]]]
>>> f(l)
[1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```