# How to make a flat list from nested lists?

Tags: python, nested

Given a nested list of integers, implement an iterator to flatten it. Each
element is either an integer, or a list -- whose elements may also be integers
or other lists. For example, if the input is `[[1,1],2,[1,1]]`, then the output
is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]`. If the input is `[1,[4,[6]]]`, then the output is `[1, 4, 6]`.

Would anyone be able to advise me as to where the code below went wrong?
I am just starting out with python.

```
def eb34(list1):
   
    flat_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if type(list[i]) == list:
            flat_list += flatten(list1[i])
        else:
            flat_list.append(list1[i])
        
    return flat_list
```

Comment: You are calling a function called `flatten()` — where is that defined? I only see a function called `eb34`. There seems to be several problems here. I would start by looking at and understanding the errors.

Comment: where you wrote `if type(list[i]) == list:` you probably want `if type(list1[i]) == list:`

Comment: Maybe `flatten()` is supposed to be `eb34()`??

Comment: @alvin-teoh, One big source of bugs in python (and any programming language) is the fact that they don't understand what you "want" to say, but only what you actually write. So, it pays to take the time to review every single name a couple of times when debugging, specially if you have been re-writing your code many times.

Comment: Related, though I don't think it's a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: The code above would actually be provided in the course material (albeit slightly changed). When things did not work out, I used the original code as it was. But it seems that there are errors as well.

Comment: The statement `type(list[i]) == list` implies that there was a variable name `list` (that you can index as `list[i]`. "list" is a reserved keyword, and therefore should never be used to name variables. If it was like that in your reference code, then yes, the reference was wrong.

Comment: Would flatten() would be a built-in function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: No, they were expecting you to write a recursive function, called `flatten()`, that would call itself in each recursion. If `eb34` is also part of the course material, well... another mistake. Maybe they're misleading you to increase the challenge :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```py
def flatten(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, list): # if not list
        return [arg]
    return [x for sub in arg for x in flatten(sub)] # recurse and collect

print(flatten([[1,1],2,[1,1]])) # [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
print(flatten([1,[4,[6]]]))     # [1, 4, 6]
```

Or to make a generator,

```py
def flatten(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, list): # if not list
        yield arg
    else:
        for sub in arg:
            yield from flatten(sub)

print(*flatten([[1,1],2,[1,1]])) # 1 1 2 1 1
print(*flatten([1,[4,[6]]]))     # 1 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know from where you are calling flatten() in your code. I am giving you a solution with the other information you have given.

```
def eb34(list1):
    flat_list = []
    for i in list1:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for j in eb34(i):
                flat_list.append(j)
        else:
            flat_list.append(i)
    return flat_list
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Try for example `[[1,[1,2]],2,[1,1]]`

Comment: Would we be able to make it work for the below case as well?
[[1], [2, [3], None], [[[4]]]]

Comment: @AlvinTeoh Oh sorry missed your other example, I have changed the code now it is working for all the cases

Comment: Does eb34(i) create a loop within the function itself? Meaning to say that the input argument would keep looping as long as there are nested lists?

Comment: yes, it will keep working unless you get your list completely flattened.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively flatten it:

```
def flatten_recursively(lst_in):
    lst_out = []
    for i in lst_in:
        if type(i) == list:
            for j in flatten_recursively(i):
                lst_out.append(j)
        else:
            lst_out.append(i)
    return lst_out
```

Also check out this answer, although you might have to adjust it to Python 3+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824420/18189622

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to make a flat list from nested lists is to use the itertools module. The itertools module has a function called chain that takes a list of lists and returns a single list.

```
 >>> import itertools
 >>> nested_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
 >>> flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*nested_lists))
 >>> flat_list
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: The question is obviously an exercise where student is supposed to come with an algorithm using atomic tools, not importing modules that "solve the problem for you". Also, please check how to answer [HW questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: This also produces an error with the first example input provided.